# Are Big-Theta functions asymptotic monotonically non decreasing?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

For example, suppose $f(n) = \Theta(n^2)$, then does that mean for any sufficiently large $n$, $f(n) \le f(n+1)$? Is it a general case for all Big-Theta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it may not be true.

Consider the following function on $\Bbb N$.

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
(n+2)^2\quad &\text{when } n \text { is odd,}\\
n^2\quad &\text{when } n \text { is even.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then $f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$. However, for all odd $n$, $f(n)>f(n+1)$. In fact, $f(n)-f(n+1)\to\infty$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$ along the odd numbers.

---

Here are two related exercises.

**Exercise 1.** Give an example of $f(n)=\Theta(n)$ such that $f(n)>f(n+1)$ for infinitely many $n$.

**Exercise 2.** Let $g(n)\ge0$ be an unbounded function on $\Bbb N$.

- Let $h(n)=\Theta(g(n))$. Prove that $h(n)<h(n+1)$ for infinitely many $n$.
- Construct $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ such that for any number $c$, $f(n)-f(n+1)>c$ for infinitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true in general: consider a function that is $\Theta(1/n)$.